# Entity Framework LINQ query issue wtih Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I wrote a simple LINQ query by comparing the date part only using the EF6 Dbfunction and it works fine and I am getting result from db

```
var dateDifference = DateTime.Now.Date;
var queryableData = DataContext.Single
       .Where(s => dateDifference  ==
 DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(s.Created.Year, s.Created.Month,
 s.Created.Day, 0, 0, 0)).ToList();
```

However, If I tried to write same LINQ Query with Expression Tree, I am not getting any result where as the query perform as usual without any error

```
var  dateDifference = DateTime.Now.Date;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "p");
propertyReference = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Created");

var constantReference = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctions), "CreateDateTime",
          null,
          new Expression[]
          {                                      
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(dateDifference.Year),typeof(int?)),
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(dateDifference.Month),typeof(int?)),
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(dateDifference.Day),typeof(int?)),
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0),typeof(int?)),
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0),typeof(int?)),
              Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0),typeof(double?)),
          });

Expression expression = Expression.Equal(propertyReference,constantReference);
```

But that above generate expression not seems to be produce any result. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you trying to write it all from scratch when you can just write a lambda and have the compiler do it for you?

Comment: I have a dynamic search criteria, the simple lambda is just for testing weather it works or not, actually I want to generate dynamic linq query using expression tree and this is the only thing left now. Wondering if I found what I am doing wrong. Should be small fix

Comment: surprise to see someone vote this question to close. My request to those who don't know the answer then at least don't make silly request.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the first sample you're checking dateDifference against CreateDateTime(s.Create) and in the second you're checking CreateDateTime(dateDifference) against parameter p.  shouldn't your constant expression just be dateDifference, and your parameter expression be built around s.Created?

Comment: Yes, you are getting it right. I don't know how it could be possible with expression tree? I certainly doing thing wrong in constantReference.. How can I translate the linq query into appropriate expression tree?

Comment: @AmmarKhan, perhaps investigate dynamicLinq and see if you can ditch putting expression trees together yourself. Putting one together yourself.